# Spring Boot: Jackson won't pick up configuration from "application.properties"

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I have a multi-module Maven-based Spring Boot Application. In one of my modules' `application.properties` file, I am setting Jackson to **not** serialize dates as timestamps (arrays), so that they are always serialized as strings (which is the fallback behavior). The property is this:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

Problem is... the property doesn't seem to be picked up by either Spring Boot/Jackson. The `java.time.LocalDate` instances I am trying to serialize always get written as timestamps. I have checked the code inside the `LocalDateSerializer.serialize(...)` method (from Jackson's own JavaTimeModule), and found this:

```
@Override
public void serialize(LocalDate date, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException
{
    if (useTimestamp(provider)) {  // This always returns true
        generator.writeStartArray();
        generator.writeNumber(date.getYear());
        generator.writeNumber(date.getMonthValue());
        generator.writeNumber(date.getDayOfMonth());
        generator.writeEndArray();
    } else {
        String str = (_formatter == null) ? date.toString() : date.format(_formatter);
        generator.writeString(str);
    }
}
```

The `useTimestamp()` method always returns true, no matter what my configuration is. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Indra's answer, I got an important clue that helped me figure out the issue.

Turns out that my Spring Boot application has multiple instances of `RestTemplate` in its application context (it is a pretty big system and relies upon some custom proprietary frameworks to work). Most of these `RestTemplate` instances were there just to support my system's architecture. There is **only one** `RestTemplate` instance that I should've cared about: The one that *I wrote* and allows my business logic to work (by enabling my system to consume remote RESTful APIs).

So, when I was trying to configure Jackson and its `ObjectMapper`, I wasn't really affecting *my* `RestTemplate` instance. By the time my configuration was read, that `RestTemplate` had long ago been initialized with the default settings provided by Spring Boot.

This is how my final configuration class looks:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate myRestTemplate(HttpMessageConverters customConverters) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 restTemplate.setMessageConverters(customConverters.getConverters());
        return restTemplate;
    }

    /*
     * The following custom HttpMessageConverter is injected into myRestTemplate
     * in order to appropriately configure the serialization/deserialization of LocalDate
     * instances into/from strings.
     */
    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());  
     mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return new HttpMessageConverters(converter);
    }

}
```

What I am doing is to explicitly configure *the `RestTemplate` instance* that needed to be configured.

The following documentation was also very helpful: [HttpMessageConverters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters). It describes how to declare custom HttpMessageConverters for use in the application context.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and an `ObjectMapper`. Here is an example configuration class,

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter 
        getMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter =
            new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ...

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ...
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        //or   
        // mapper.configure(
        // SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return converter;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: I have usually done the way I showed in my above example. More control on the behavior of the `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Creating a custom `HttpMessageConverter` allowed me to realize that I had to explicitly inject that into the `RestTemplate` instance I was trying to configure. I added an answer detailing my findings. :)